# Expression that means one thing happened after another

Tags: expressions

I've heard an expression before which basically meant that 2 things happened one after the other and for the life of me I can't remember it. I think it was used in a negative connotation. It went something like this, first comes the ____ then the ____. Please help if you know this. Thanks

Comment: former, latter?

Comment: No it's nothing that simple, it sounded like something out of a Shakespeare novel. It meant one bad thing happened right after another bad thing.

Comment: *cookies* and *baseball bat*? hammer and anvil? cloud then rain?

Comment: The idiomatic thing is, in fact, *one thing after another*.

Comment: No that's not it but thank you for replying though, those are some good ones that'll I'll use instead in the mean time

Comment: A very very broad ? here.

Comment: Two particular things, or things that have to follow from other things in general?

Comment: I'm glad you want to participate, but really, there are a lot of these, and it's going to be a long  guessing-game slog without some more context. The first one I can think of involves a horse and a cart. Does that ring a bell?

Answer (score 2):

Two things that happen consecutively (one after the other).

First one thing, then another.

Where there's smoke, there's fire.

Pride goes before a fall.

Sometimes bad things have to happen before good things can.

One woe doth tread upon another’s heel.
The bad news just keeps on coming, one disaster after another.

When Envy breeds unkind division: there comes the ruin, there begins confusion. It must follow as the night the day.

First comes love then comes marriage. Then comes [INSERT NAME] with a baby carriage.

Comment: Meant to type happen, not happens

Comment: You can just edit your answers (and questions). Welcome to ELU.